# My application crash while recording second video

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mediarecorder, android-video-record

I'm  developing  a  mobile  application  about  recording  a  video  using  a  SurfaceView. I  want  to  record multiple  videos  using  MediaRecorder  but  my  app  crash  while  recording  second  video. I can  record  first  video  successfully. I  searched  about  some  solutions  but  nothing  worked  for  me.  Thanks, this  is  my  code

```
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {                                                                                               
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                                                                                                         
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);                                                                                                    

     // we shall take the video in landscape orientation                                                                                         
     context=this ;                                                                                                                              
     mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);                                                                                
     mHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();                                                                                                         
     mHolder.addCallback(this);                                                                                                                  
     mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);                                                                                   
     FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);                                                                                          
     mMediaRecorder=new MediaRecorder();                                                                                                         
     //mToggleButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleRecordingButton);                                                                  
     fab.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {                                                                                         
         @Override                                                                                                                               
         public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent Event) {                                                                                  


             if (Event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {                                                                                 
                 Toast.makeText(context, "Recording started!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                                                       

              if (mMediaRecorder!=null) {                                                                                            
                         mMediaRecorder=null;                                                                                                    
                         try {                                                                                                                   
                             initRecorder(mHolder.getSurface());                                                                                 
                         } catch (IOException e) {                                                                                               
                             e.printStackTrace();                                                                                                
                         }                                                                                                                       
                         Log.d("s2", "dkhalt start2");                                                                                           

                         try {                                                                                                                   
                             //mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(myfile);                                                                             

                             record_audio();                                                                                                     
                             Log.d("started_2", "started_2");                                                                                    

                         } catch (IllegalStateException e) {                                                                                     
                             e.printStackTrace();                                                                                                
                         }                                                                                                                       

                     }                                                                                                                           
             }else if (Event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {                                                                             

                mMediaRecorder.stop();                                                                                                           
                mMediaRecorder.reset();                                                                                                          
               //  shutdown();                                                                                                                   


                 Toast.makeText(video.this, "Recording finished", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                                                     

                 Toast.makeText(context, "Recorded.!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                                                               
             }                                                                                                                                   
             return false;                                                                                                                       
         }                                                                                                                                       
     });                                                                                                                                         

 }                                                                                                                                               

      private void initRecorder(Surface surface) throws IOException {                                                                                 

     String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/MyVideos/";                                                   
     File dir = new File(path);                                                                                                                  
     if (!dir.exists())                                                                                                                          
         dir.mkdirs();                                                                                                                           
     String myfile = path + "houssam" + i + ".mp4";                                                                                              
     if (checkPermissionREAD_EXTERNAL_STORAGE(context)) {                                                                                        
         if (mCamera == null) {                                                                                                                  
             mCamera = Camera.open();                                                                                                            
             mCamera.unlock();                                                                                                                   
         }                                                                                                                                       



         mMediaRecorder=new MediaRecorder();                                                                                                     


         mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surface);                                                                                              
         mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);                                                                                                      

         mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);                                                                       
         mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);                                                                      
         mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);                                                                        
         mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(512 * 1000);                                                                                     
         mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);                                                                                                   
         //mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(640, 480);                                                                                                
             mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(myfile);                                                                                               
         mMediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(3000); // 20 seconds                                                                                      



         try {                                                                                                                                   

             mMediaRecorder.prepare();                                                                                                           
             mMediaRecorder.start();                                                                                                             
         } catch (IllegalStateException e) {                                                                                                     
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block                                                                                                  
             e.printStackTrace();                                                                                                                
         } catch (IOException e) {                                                                                                               
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block                                                                                                  
             e.printStackTrace();                                                                                                                
         }                                                                                                                                       


         mInitSuccesful = true;                                                                                                                  

           i++;                                                                                                                                            


     }                                                                                                                                               


     else                                                                                                                                        
     {        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(video.this, new String[] 
     {WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, RECORD_AUDIO,CAMERA}, RequestPermissionCode) ;  
     }                                                                                                                                           

        }                                                                                                                                               
     public void record_audio(){                                                                                                                     
     if (checkPermissionREAD_EXTERNAL_STORAGE(context)) {                                                                                        

         mMediaRecorder.setOnInfoListener(this);                                                                                                 



         try {                                                                                                                                   

             mMediaRecorder.prepare();                                                                                                           
             mMediaRecorder.start();                                                                                                             
         } catch (IllegalStateException e) {                                                                                                     
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block                                                                                                  
             e.printStackTrace();                                                                                                                
         } catch (IOException e) {                                                                                                               
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block                                                                                                  
             e.printStackTrace();                                                                                                                
         }                                                                                                                                       

     }                                                                                                                                           
     else { ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(video.this, new String[] 
     {WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, RECORD_AUDIO,CAMERA}, RequestPermissionCode) ;}   
      }                                                                                                                                               

     @Override                                                                                                                                       
      public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {                                                                                              
     try {                                                                                                                                       
         if (!mInitSuccesful)                                                                                                                    
             initRecorder(mHolder.getSurface());                                                                                                 
     } catch (IOException e) {                                                                                                                   
         e.printStackTrace();                                                                                                                    
     }                                                                                                                                           
     }                                                                                                                                               

    @Override                                                                                                                                       
     public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {                                                                                            
     shutdown();                                                                                                                                 
     }                                                                                                                                               

      @Override                                                                                                                                       
      public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, 
       int height) {                                                           

     }                                                                                                                                               

    private void shutdown() {                                                                                                                       
     // Release MediaRecorder and especially the Camera as it's a shared                                                                         
     // object that can be used by other applications                                                                                            

     if(null !=mMediaRecorder && mCamera!=null) {                                                                                                
         try {                                                                                                                                   
             mMediaRecorder.reset();                                                                                                             
             mMediaRecorder.release();                                                                                                           
             mCamera.release();                                                                                                                  

             // once the objects have been released they can't be reused                                                                         
             mMediaRecorder = null;                                                                                                              
             mCamera = null;                                                                                                                     

         }                                                                                                                                       
         catch (RuntimeException e) {e.getMessage();}                                                                                            
     }                                                                                                                                           
 }                                                                                                                                               

      @Override   

    public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mediaRecorder, int i, int i1) {                                                                                
     if (i == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED) {                                                                          

         mMediaRecorder.stop();                                                                                                                  
         Log.v("VIDEOCAPTURE","Maximum Duration Reached");                                                                                       
         Toast.makeText(context, "Maximum Duration Reached", 
         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                                                         
         }                                                                                                                                           
       }
```

````
08-03 16:06:51.138 30868-30868/com.example.android.roomwordssample 
        E/MediaRecorder: start failed: -19
       08-03 16:06:51.138 30868-30868/com.example.android.roomwordssample 
       E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
        08-03 16:06:51.138 30868-30868/com.example.android.roomwordssample 
        E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: 
        handleReceiveCallback
       08-03 16:06:51.168 30868-30868/com.example.android.roomwordssample 
       E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
        at android.media.MediaRecorder._start(Native Method)
        at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(MediaRecorder.java:946)
08-03 17:04:11.778 15665-15665/com.example.android.roomwordssample E/MediaRecorder: start failed: -19
08-03 17:04:11.798 15665-15665/com.example.android.roomwordssample E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
08-03 17:04:11.798 15665-15665/com.example.android.roomwordssample E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
08-03 17:04:11.828 15665-15665/com.example.android.roomwordssample E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
        at android.media.MediaRecorder._start(Native Method)
        at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(MediaRecorder.java:946)
        at com.example.lab.Activities.video.record_audio(video.java:197)
        at com.example.lab.Activities.video$1.onTouch(video.java:101)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9987)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2839)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2456)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2839)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2456)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2839)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2456)

        ```
````

Comment: Can you add the full stacktrace to your question? You probably should refactor the `shutdown` method as well. You want to have different `try catch` blocks for `mediaRecorder` and `camera` and the `set to null` in their respective `finally` block, to mare sure that both are set to `null` in case they produce an exception.

Comment: i addded full trace ,please if u have any suggestion , more than 1 week and im searching for solutions

Comment: You shold probably clean up your example code first and try it again. As mentioned before change the `shutdown` and change the start of the recording as well (I doubt you can start recording if your `initRecorder(...)` failed). Also did you check your log (you'll probably want to put all you `e.printStackTrace()`to the log as well, not sure where they and up currently)  for any additional exception that might have occured before the one you posted.

Comment: While you are it reconsider all your other `try catch` blocks as just supressing the exception and then continueing is most of the times the wrong approach.